# how to setup masterpage programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

the function

```
private void SetUpMasterPage(){
    this.MasterPageFile = "~/MasterPages/NestedMasterPageTest2.Master"; 
}
```

is called on the OnPreInit... This works when the masterpagefile is the base masterpage... But how are we going to make it work for the nested masterpage?

we actually tried

```
this.Master.MasterPageFile = "~/MasterPages/Base.Master";
```

but it throws an exception... =(

---

So, to make things clearer, on the aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test._Default"%>
<asp:Content ID="testContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" runat="server">
This is a test!
</asp:Content>
```

on the base.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Base.master.cs" Inherits="Test.Base" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>The title</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="body" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and on the default.aspx.cs

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e){
    this.MasterPageFile = "~/MasterPages/Base.Master";
}
```

*it is working...*

---

but when I use a `nested master page`

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Base.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NestedMasterPageTest2.master.cs" Inherits="Test.MasterPages.NestedMasterPageTest2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

then changed the default.aspx.cs

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e){
    this.MasterPageFile ="~/MasterPages/NestedMasterPageTest2.Master";
}
```

and I changed the default.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="testContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content2" runat="server">
This is a test which uses a nested master page!
</asp:Content>
```

it returns an error that says `Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder 'Content2' in the master page '/MasterPages/NestedMasterPageTest2.Master', verify content control's ContentPlaceHolderID attribute in the content page.` But `Content2` is on `NestedMasterPageTest2`. What really must have happened here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested master page has Content control but no ContentPlaceHolder control. Try adding it:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cplh" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Then, in Default.aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="cnt1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cplh" runat="server">
  This is a test which uses a nested master page!
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `<asp:ContentPlaceholder>` tag to your nested master page:

```
<asp:Content ID="basebody" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content2" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
```